# play mp3 without opening a new page

Tags: javascript

When click on play audio on most websites, [this one](http://ru.forvo.com/word/get/#en) for example, the mp3 is played without opening a new webpage. However, when I request mp3 from my server with the link -/mysite/test.mp3, the broswer opens up a new window to play it. How can I stop browser from opening a new window and just play it on the same page it was requested from?

I've also found out that this site uses the following:

```
onClick="Play(566950,'OTA0OTk5OS8zOS85MDQ5OTk5XzM5XzU5NTRfNTI2MzA4Lm1wMw==','OTA0OTk5OS8zOS85MDQ5OTk5XzM5XzU5NTRfNTI2MzA4Lm9nZw==');return false;"
```

What could they be doing?

Comment: There is no code, it's just link

Answer (score 0):

Use the [html5 audio tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp):

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="-/mysite/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not supported in IE8, and I'm targeting this browser as well.

Comment: IE8 doesn't support HTML5. Use some flash audio players. http://www.4templates.com/tutorials/embedding-audio-on-your-website-with-a-flash-audio-player/

Comment: You may also want to take a look at aurora.js.